# SQL Server trigger on insert

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, triggers

When I try to insert a new record into the table I created the trigger on it does not create.

This is after I activated the trigger. When I deactivate it then repeated the insert, it goes through. What am I missing in my trigger?

My trigger identifies all the new rows in a table then emails them to a recipient.

This is my trigger

```
USE [paldbCAT_TEST]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[LPO_ON_INSERT]    Script Date: 10-11-2020 12:09:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER trigger [dbo].[LPO_ON_INSERT] 
ON [dbo].[tblOrdersDocP_POApprovals]
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS

Declare
@HTMLbody nvarchar (max),
@strOrdPDocID varchar(100),
@strSelectedApproverUserName varchar(50),
@SQL nvarchar(max)

SET @SQL =''

Set @HTMLbody = '<html><head><title> System Tables</title></head><body>'
Set @HTMLbody = @HTMLbody + '<center>       <h1 style="font-family: arial, sans-serif">Purchase Requisition(s) awaiting approvals.</h1></center>'
Set @HTMLbody = @HTMLbody + '<center><table style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;" ><TH style="background-color:black; color:white;border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;">Document Number</TH><TH style="background-color:black; color:white;border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;">Document Approver</TH>'

declare SystemTable cursor

for
select strOrdPDocID,strSelectedApproverUserName from tblOrdersDocP_POApprovals
open SystemTable
Fetch next from SystemTable into @strOrdPDocID,@strSelectedApproverUserName


While (@@FETCH_STATUS<> -1)
Begin
Set @SQL = @SQL + '<TR><TD style=" border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;">' +@strOrdPDocID + '</TD><TD style=" border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;">' + @strSelectedApproverUserName + '</TD></TR>'

Fetch next from SystemTable into @strOrdPDocID,@strSelectedApproverUserName
End
Close SystemTable
DEALLOCATE SystemTable


Set @HTMLbody = @HTMLbody + @SQL + '</table></center></body></html>'




EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'CatNotificationsMain',
@recipients = 'test@gmail.com',
@subject = 'Database Record Deleted',
@body_format='HTML',
@body = @HTMLbody,
@attach_query_result_as_file = 0;
```

Comment: This does not look like a trigger. It never uses inserted/deleted, and it misses CREATE TRIGGER, so we don't know if it's really trigger

Comment: Hi take a look at the amendments

Comment: Your trigger is "INSTEAD OF INSERT". As this name implies - it runs _instead of_ insert, so actual insert doesn't occur.

Comment: Hey i just found a solution @Evk  , the statement "INSTEAD OF INSERT" was  the detriment

Comment: Note that you should access rows being inserted via "INSERTED" reference, not like you are doing now.

Answer (score 2):

Your are creating the trigger making it replace the INSERT statement, as long as your trigger does notify the insertion, it should be run AFTER the insert has happened.

You can do further reading on the trigger types in the [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
ALTER trigger [dbo].[LPO_ON_INSERT] 
ON [dbo].[tblOrdersDocP_POApprovals]
AFTER INSERT AS
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i just found a solution @Evk , the statement "INSTEAD OF INSERT" was the detriment

Comment: pretty much what I told you in my answer, glad you found the problem. Happy coding!